# Saving variable as subclass (interface)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I'm making an AsyncTask extension that communicates with a service using different actions and returns different types of results depending on the action used. Each action has a listener, made of interfaces extending one interface called `OnCommunicationFailedListener`. The thing is, I want to have only one variable to save the listener, `OnCommunicationFailedListener` type, and make the user be able to save all "sub-interfaces" in that variable. They can save them just as is, but I cannot call the methods that the "sub-interface" introduces.

```
class CommunicationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private Action action;  
    private OnCommunicationFailedListener listener;

    enum Action {
        LOGIN,
        LOGOUT,
        SEARCH
    }

    interface OnCommunicationFailedListener {
        void onCommunicationFailed();
    }

    interface OnLoginAchievedListener extends OnCommunicationFailedListener {
        void onLoggedIn(String result);
        void onLoginError(String error);
    }

    interface OnLogoutAchievedListener extends OnCommunicationFailedListener {
        void onLoggedOut(String result);
        void onLogoutError(String error);
    }

    interface OnSearchAchievedListener extends OnCommunicationFailedListener {
        void onSearchAchieved(String[] results);
    }

    @Override protected String doInBackground(Void... voids){
        try {
            // Try to communicate with a query, resulting in some result.
            return result;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result == null) {
            listener.onCommunicationFailed();
            return;
        }

        // ALL OF THESE GIVE ERRORS, SINCE THE METHODS DO NOT EXIST ANYMORE
        switch(action){
            case LOGIN:
                if(<check if result is ok>){
                    listener.onLoggedIn(result);
                } else listener.onLoginError(<some error>);
                break;

            case LOGOUT:
                if(<check if result is ok>){
                    listener.onLoggedOut(result);
                } else listener.onLogoutError(<some error>);
                break;

            case SEARCH:
                String[] results = <process result>;
                listener.onSearchAchieved(results);
                break;
        }
    }

    void login(String user, String password, OnLoginAchievedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
        action = Action.LOGIN;

        //Build the query...

        execute();
    }

    void logout(OnLogoutAchievedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
        action = Action.LOGOUT;

        //Build the query...

        execute();
    }

    void search(String query, OnSearchAchievedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
        action = Action.SEARCH;

        //Build the query...

        execute();
    }
}
```

The idea is that another class calls the methods `login()`, `logout()` or `search()` and gives them a listener of the action's type. When the communication is finalized and the result is acquired, the action's listener methods are called (in my code, this happens in the `switch` statement).

The thing is, these methods cannot be called since the passed listener has been casted to `OnCommunicationFailedListener`.

Is there any way to save a subclass in a variable of its superclass type without being casted to it? I don't want to have actual variables for every type of listener.

Comment: You don't show enough code to give an exact indication what's wrong about your design, but if you're at the position where you want to call a subclass (like the login handler), you should definitely be maintaining that subclass of the interface rather than the generic parent one.

Comment: OnCommunicationFailedListener should not be your super class, extract the methods which are common between the FailedListener and AchievedListener to a more general Listener. But maybe you should read up a little more about inheritance

Comment: @Laurens what I say is I will have some other listener that also do implement the "failed" one, so when the result of the operation in the class is null I will call `listener.onCommunicationFailed()`, without depending of which type the listener is.

Comment: I can't work out what you're trying to achieve, or what you are doing about it. Can you please reword some of the question to make it clearer and add more code? Thx

Comment: @EngineerDollery editing...